# Creating an bomb-proof worker process (on windows)

Tags: windows, security, process, isolation

I write a pdf viewer that uses various libraries written in C. This C code is potentially easy to exploit. And there are just too many lines to check. I will have to assume that this code may contain exploitable bugs.

The thing is that the C code is quite straightforward. A stream of bytes go in at one end, and a bitmap (also a stream of bytes) comes out at the other.

Inspired by google chrome, I am thinking to create a separate process that does the decoding and page rendering. Ideally this should be executed in a process that has absolutely no rights to do anything except reading the one input stream it has, and outputting to a stream of bytes (some uncompresed bitmap) at the other end.

What I think the process should not be able to do is:

- any disk access
- open sockets
- limited amount of memory use
- access shared memory with other processes
- load other dll's
- ... anything else?

Is that possible? Is this described somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a lightweight, programmable Sandbox API for the Windows platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016731/is-there-a-lightweight-programmable-sandbox-api-for-the-windows-platform)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code - you may check it doesn't do the described things.
Well, limiting available memory is a bit more difficult. You may however use `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`.

Also after you've built the executable you may check its DLL import table (by dependencies walker) to ensure it doesn't access any file/socket function.

Comment: What I am talking about is things that I don't want exploit code to be able to do. I think it is still possible to run functions from dll's visible to the process, by querying their adress at runtime. I am looking for a line of defense at the OS level.

Comment: You may also check the code doesn't import `LoadLibraryX` and `GetProcAddress`. Hence - the code won't probably be able to use any other socket/file function. Unless it's a really **badly** expoloited code, which may at runtime scan the mapped into memory kernel32.dll and locate the needed function in its export table.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really possible.  Ultimately any potential exploit code will be running with whatever privileges this process runs with.  If you run it as a standard user then you will limit the damage that could be done, but your best bet is to just fix the code as much as possible.

Comment: I agree that the exploit is only limited to the processes privileges. So the idea is to reduce those privileges to the bare minimum.

Comment: You could create a new group/user and use the local security policy to severely restrict it, but that seems a bit extreme for a little PDF viewer.