# Windows base image for docker

Tags: docker

Is there a windows server base image for docker? I'm using boot2docker and I understand it runs an in memory VM based on Tiny Core Linux. All the docker files I see on docker hub have a Linux base image e.g. FROM debian:wheezy. I obviously haven't look at all of them.

Does anyone know if a windows server base image exists or is in the works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docker.io for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854240/docker-io-for-windows)

Answer (score 1):

That's, for now, impossible because Mircosoft is willing to implement a docker like behavior but is far away to be launching features like that.

see http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-microsoft-partner-distributed-applications/

Comment: Thanks the section named "Docker Engine for Windows Server" detailed what I needed to know. So for now anything .NET on docker will be via Mono.